# How can I autofill empty space under column with dynamic content height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my theme I have product filters(col-3) on left side and products listing on right side(col-9). Filters height is dynamic depending on content size (usually takes 2-3 rows in comparison to products on right side). I would like to use  empty space under filters to fill it with products but  structure itself cause a problem. So question is - is it possible in fairly simple way to fill left side without js manipulations?

Here is expected result (yellow products): https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Sjn.jpg

Here is current structure:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 bg-info">
      FILTERS HTML
    </div>

    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 bg-warning">
          PRODUCT HTML
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          PRODUCT HTML
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 bg-warning">
          PRODUCT HTML
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          PRODUCT HTML
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          PRODUCT HTML
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 bg-warning">
          PRODUCT HTML
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          PRODUCT HTML
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 bg-warning">
          PRODUCT HTML
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. As you can see above, then filters column _is_ full height, so there's space for additional content. Please revise to explain the problem better.

Comment: This should probably rather be solved using `float`, than flexbox.